# Access StringWriter contents as stream

Tags: java, json, string, stream, buffer

I want to compile a large document as JSON from several smaller documents stored in my MongoDB. I've written a Java function to compile my document, and now I want my application to have access to the JSON in order to either return it to the client, or to do further processing on it.

My problem is that instantiating the JSON string can take up a lot of memory, and I have started to run into OutOfMemoryErrors because of this. I've implemented my own version of the toJSON method from the MongoDB library that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Borrowed from the MongoDB toJSON method for Documents, except we dont instantiate the json string and return the writer instead.
 *
 * @return a buffer containing the JSON representation of the given document
 * @throws org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException if the registry does not contain a codec for the document values.
 */
private Writer toJson(Document document) {
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new StringWriter(), new JsonWriterSettings(true));
        new DocumentCodec().encode(writer, document, EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());
        return writer.getWriter();
}
```

Instead of returning a string, this method returns the writer that has the JSON string buffered. Now I would like to use this in my application *without* calling the toString() method like I've seen in many examples online. The closest example I've found is the solution [at the bottom of this page](https://www.genuitec.com/dump-a-stringbuilder-to-file/).

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("TempFile1mod"))) {
    final int aLength = aSB.length();
    final int aChunk = 1024;// 1 kb buffer to read data from 
    final char[] aChars = new char[aChunk];

    for (int aPosStart = 0; aPosStart < aLength; aPosStart += aChunk) {
    final int aPosEnd = Math.min(aPosStart + aChunk, aLength);
    aSB.getChars(aPosStart, aPosEnd, aChars, 0); // Create no new buffer
    bw.write(aChars, 0, aPosEnd - aPosStart);// This is faster than just copying one byte at the time
    }
```

This does do what I want, and would allow me to write my string in chunks to any stream. However, since this seems to me like such a common use case, I would have expected Java to have some generic way to pipe my data out of the string buffer and into another stream.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, there are libraries like Apache Commons IO that provide utility methods like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Thomas for the suggestion. I ended up passing my StringBuffer into a [CharSequenceInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CharSequenceInputStream.html) like this:

```
/**
 * Borrowed from the MongoDB toJSON method for Documents, except we dont
 * instantiate the JSON String but return an InputStream instead.
 *
 * @return a buffer containing the JSON representation of the given document
 * @throws org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException if the
 *         registry does not contain a codec for the document values.
 */
private InputStream toJson(Document document) {
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new StringWriter(), new JsonWriterSettings(true));

    new DocumentCodec().encode(writer, document,
            EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());

    CharSequence result = ((StringWriter) writer.getWriter()).getBuffer();

    return new CharSequenceInputStream(result, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```